# Compliling c programs to C89/C90 standard in VSC

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, c89

I'm learning C90/90 in uni using MinGW compiler.
Now I want to use VSC instead of CodeBlocks which my prof uses.

How would I go about changing the compilers settings to disallow any functions that are not included within C90?

Comment: You need to add option `-std=c90`  to the compiler command for gcc. Check VS Code documentation about how to to this. IIRC you need to modify file `tasks.json` in your workplace folder.

Comment: When learning, stick to whatever the prof is using, unless it is propietary/expensive and you want to use something Free or for free. I don't see this is the case here. Learning c is is difficult enough as it is, you don't want the extra hassle of being different. When needing to configure project specific options for compiler and linker, the prof can help you if you are using MinGW/CodeBlocs, but not if you are using VSC.

Comment: For any gcc-like compiler: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) IDE doesn't matter. If you are going for a degree in dinosaur programming, then simply switch the standard to `-std=c90`.

Comment: I recommend that you also compile with `-std=c90 -pedantic-errors`, so that the compiler enforces strict compliance with the standard.